# ArToolkit, Android and 2D markers

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, artoolkit

I've encountered some problems using ArCode with 2D bar code inside.
I'm using Android and the ArToolkit.

I've no problem recognizing "Hiro" marker or the "kanji".
Sometimes, artoolkit confuses "0" bar code with "hiro", but this is not the problem, the problem is that I can't, in any way I've tried, recognize a 2D bar code.

This is my code :

```
if (!ARToolKit.getInstance().initialiseNative(this.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()) ||
        !ARToolKit.getInstance().initialiseAR(640, 480, "Data/camera_para.dat", 0, false)) {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "errore di inizializzazione");
    return;
}
_markerID = ARToolKit.getInstance().addMarker("single_barcode;0;40");
```

it doesn't count if I use :

single_barcode;0;10
...
single_barcode;0;80

obiviosly with instead:

```
   _markerID = ARToolKit.getInstance().addMarker("single;Data/patt.hiro;10");
```

it works.

I've tried aldo to create a file like the one for hiro ( patt.hiro) and kanji (patt.kanji). 
So, I've created a  code.dat

```
1

00
40.0
1.0000  0.0000  0.0000    0.0000
0.0000  1.0000  0.0000    0.0000
0.0000  0.0000  1.0000    0.0000
```

for the "0" bar code.

```
_markerID = ARToolKit.getInstance().addMarker("single;Data/code.dat;40");
```

Again it doesn't count if I use :

single;Data/code.dat;10
..
single;Data/code.dat;80

but again nothing.

I can't find any valid example using this in android, or any exaustive manual...

Where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

The usage of 2D Barcode for ARToolkit in Android is not available in any public documentation. However, if you refer directly to the ARWrapper source code. I found it is available through NativeInterface and ARToolkit.

Here's a working example I used in my Android App

Firstly, do something like this in your detection initialization

```
NativeInterface.arwSetPatternDetectionMode(NativeInterface.AR_MATRIX_CODE_DETECTION);
NativeInterface.arwSetMatrixCodeType(NativeInterface.AR_MATRIX_CODE_3x3_PARITY65);
markerID = ARToolKit.getInstance().addMarker("single_barcode;0;80");
```

For 2D Barcode (Matrix code) detection, you must set the pattern detection mode as `AR_MATRIX_CODE_DETECTION`. For details of different matrix code type, you may refer to the official documentation. I am using the default ones provided under /artoolkit5/doc/patterns from the github repository.

The configuration string for single barcode detection is using the following format, `"single_barcode;<barcode ID>;<Marker Width>"`.

The rest should be the same as using pattern marker. Just for clarification purpose, after calling `ARToolKit.getInstance().convertAndDetect(frame)` which is usually in your Activity which inherited from ARActivity, you may query it's visibility using `ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerVisible(markerID)` as usual.

**References**

https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in another question, everything into the assets folder is cached by ARToolkit and when you add new markers you need to either increase the version number of the app or to uninstall it.

You do not need to recompile the NDK to add new markers.

Also, the string formatting is very important:

The default one is:

```
_markerID = ARToolKit.getInstance().addMarker("single;Data/patt.hiro;10");
```

for your marker you are using:

```
_markerID = ARToolKit.getInstance().addMarker("single_barcode;0;40");
```

The string defining your marker should be: 
"single;Data/single_barcode;40"

Where (as explained in this page http://www.artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_developing) the parameters mean:

- single means it is a single marker
- Data/single_barcode is the path to the file inside the assets folder (assuming you put it in the same dir as the hiro and kanji ones)
- 40 is the size of the marker in the real world, in milimeters.

And I agree that the documentation of ARToolkit needs to be improved.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that if you're trying to enumerate single/barcode markers in a DAT file, and not a multi-marker, you do not include the 4x4 transformation matrix. The transformation matrix is used to describe the concrete physical relationship between markers in a multi-marker set.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Shalafi, I've tried but nothing happen.
I've found a japanese page in which they say that you have to change a parameter and recompile the entire ArToolkit in C++ in order to make it recognize 2d code.
But ora 2d code or Arcode like hiro.

Has someone  some more detailed instructions ?

The japanese page is this : http://sixwish.jp/ARTK4Android/Wrapper/section03/
(I've translated it with google translator )

Comment: I am personally in favor of letting the NDK alone. I've managed to link jPCT-AE to ARToolkit, but I still have some offset problems to fix before I can write a detailed HOWTO about it.

On the other hand, the Unity plugin is much more mature, since it already interacts with a 3D engine.